# Grab TextBox-Value in cshtml from JavaScript

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to call an ActionUrl with JavaScript. I have a few TextBoxes in my View. Like this:

View:

```
@Html.Label("Suchbegriff")
@Html.TextBox("GeneralSearchTextBox")

@Html.Label("Strasse")
@Html.TextBox("StreetTextBox")
```

And I have controller with a method like this:

Controller:

```
public ActionResult FindAdress(int id = 0, string street = "", string city = "", string plz = "", string name = "")
    {
        DoSomethingSpecialWithTheParameters;
    }
```

My problem is, I want to pass the values from the TextBoxes into my FindAdress(...) Method, using JavaScript.

I started to build a JavaScript-Function like this:

View (Just the script-part):

```
function search()
    {
        window.navigate('@Url.Action("FindAdress", "Home",
                        new
                        {
                            id=3,
                            street = ?????
                        },
                        null)');
    }
```

I dont know how I can access the TextBoxes from here.
Any Ideas?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Is your `search`function in the same `cshtml` file as the inputs?

Comment: Yes it is in the same file..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want to redirect to the `FindAdress()` method

```
function search() {
  var street = document.getElementById("StreetTextBox").value;
  var id = ....
  var city = ....
  // other values
  var url = '@Url.Action("FindAdress", "Home")';
  document.location.href = url + '?id=' + id + '&street=' + street + '&city=' + city; // plus other values
```

Answer (score 0):

$("#textBoxId").val():

Should be the answer to getting the textbox values. Am I missing something?